# Hosting Chromecast receiver app on home server

Tags: android, chromecast, self-hosting

I'm going about building my first Chromecast application, the plans is to build a board game that will be displayed on the screen using the chromecast receiver application.

I'm a student so cash is tight, at the moment I have 3 websites hosted on my LAN, using a raspberry Pi 1 to host two of the websites on an Apache server and a Raspberry Pi 2 to host a Play-Framework application.

I want to host my chromecast receiver app on the Raspberry Pi 2 (removing the Play application), but was unsure after reading the docs on [Googles](http://developers.google.com/cast) website weather this would be possible.

Anybody have any insight into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not planing to publish your app, you can do that; make sure you use the IP address of the server rather than a name when you register your receiver (otherwise chromecast won't be able to access your server); this also means you have to make sure the IP address of your web server doesn't change. The other options that you have are:

- Use Google Drive to host your receiver: for personal use, it is good enough (we have documentation on how you can set that up, it is a little bit different from just sharing a doc)
- Use App Engine for hosting.

Both of these solutions are free for your development and personal use; the advantage of them is that you can use a real name rather then IP address.

Update: Google Drive is no longer a solution for this.

Comment: could you point me to the documentation for hosting on Google Drive?

I'm developing my game using Phaser.js, having a bit of trouble getting it up and running.